# Object.GetType() throws an error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a call like this,

```
SomeList.Fetch(x => SomeCondition).OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(sort).GetValue(x, null))
```

I get an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object at System.Object.GetType()`.

Any idea what might be causing this? This happens in-frequently and only in production.

Thanks.

Comment: The sequence output by `Fetch` contains a null element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to happen not in production but in development add a null item to your list via the Fetch. That's the reason of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your chain of events there causes you to force operations on items that may not exist. Consider adding a .Where(condition) before you call any properties. That way if the item doesn't exist, it won't attempt to perform an action on it, avoiding the null error

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your null reference exception:

```
SomeList.Fetch(x => SomeCondition)
  .Where(i => null!=i)
  .OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(sort).GetValue(x, null))
```